# Replacing items in message queue

Tags: message-queue, azureservicebus

Our system requirements say that we need to build a slightly unusual producer-consumer processing system. Imagine we have multiple data streams and we take a snapshot each X seconds and put it into the queue for processing. The streams count is not constant. The more clients we have, the more streams we need to process. At the same time, we don't need to process ALL taken snapshots. If we have too many clients and we are not able to process all items in real-time, we would prefer to skip old snapshots and process only the latest ones.

So as I see, the requirements can be met by keeping only one item in a queue for each stream. If there is a new snapshot, while the previous is still there, we need to REPLACE it using stream id as a key.
Is it possible to implement such behavior by Service Bus queue or something similar? Or maybe it makes sense to look into some other solutions like Redis?

Answer (score 0):

> So as I see, the requirements can be met by keeping only one item in a
>   queue for each stream. If there is a new snapshot, while the previous
>   is still there, we need to REPLACE it using stream id as a key. Is it
>   possible to implement such behavior by Service Bus queue or something
>   similar?

To the best of my knowledge, Azure Service Bus does not support this scenario. Through it's [`duplicate detection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) functionality, in fact it supports exact opposite of that. You would need to use some other mechanism (like Redis Cache you mentioned) to accomplish this.